# Why am I receiving a NaN on parsing an number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't find why I'm receiving a `NaN` for printing a number out with javascript.

The following code I use is repeated elsewhere on the website and works fine.

The URL in question is: http://all-american-gold10.mybigcommerce.com/us-silver-eagles/

My code is as follows:

```
    function setCheckPrice() {
  $('.NormalPrice').each(function(key, val) {
  var price = $(val).html().replace('$', '').replace(',', '');
  var newPrice = parseInt(price) * .03;
  var setPrice = Math.floor(price - newPrice);

        var credit = '<small style="font-size: 20px !important;"> - credit card price</small>';
        var check = '<p><em class="new-price">$' + setPrice +'<small style="font-size: 20px !important;"> - check price</small></em></p>';

        $(val).append(credit);

        $(val).prepend(check);



        })

};

setCheckPrice();
```

My code takes a number found by a specific class name, does some math and spits in back out with some extra html to go along with it. I've tried to switch the ways I've outputted the code with `append`, `prepend`, `before` & `after`, but none seem to work? Any reason why this is acting so strange?

Comment: Please update question with your markup too

Comment: @Pointy That’s not true. If you pass a string, it replaces the substring literally.

Comment: Just add `console.log(price)` and see what you've really got

Comment: @Xufox my gosh you're right; I must have dreamed reading otherwise (but it seemed so real!) :)

Comment: Are there leading spaces that need to be trimmed off?

Comment: In your code you are trying to loop through $('.NormalPrice') using each 
but $('.NormalPrice') is not returning an array.

Comment: @Geeky Then what is it returning?

Comment: Technically, it's returning an array-like object, but that's exactly what `.each()` iterates over.

Comment: Ya each does iterates over array.but when i tried to check in the console of the site OP has mentioned i can single element being returned not an array

Comment: @Geeky An array is a single value.

Comment: An array is a single value? I didnot get it

Answer (score 1):

The `price` variable has additional html in it. You should consider having separate elements with a class that contains just the value that you need, and nothing else. As a quick fix, this change:

```
var price = $(val).val().replace('$', '').replace(',', '').replace(" ","");
```

get's me a value of 490 for `price` on that page, which is what you're looking for.

Comment: The value I'm looking for is the modified price which is still returning a NaN with the code you suggested. console.log(price) returns 490 which is correct, but I'm trying to display the value of var setPrice which is where the NaN is coming from.

Comment: Since price has html markup in it, both newPrice and setPrice will be NaN. The root of your immediate issue is that this: var price =  $(val).html().replace('$', '').replace(',', ''); returns a bunch of html markup that can not be parsed properly into an integer. Consider cleaning up your html to begin with, if you have control over that.